# Spring scheduled no funciona al arrancar la aplicación

Tags: java, spring, schedule

Tenemos varias aplicaciones con Spring que ofrecen servicios REST, pero además hemos añadido un par de procesos planificados para que se ejecuten de forma autónoma pero hemos descubierto que cuando arranca la aplicación no funcionan los procesos planificados pero que después de una llamada a un servicio REST comienzan a funcionar.

El comportamiento es el siguiente: Al arrancar el planificador parece que no está levantado y procesos planificados no se ejecutan, pero en el momento en el que se realiza una petición a cualquier servicio rest empiezan a funcionar. ¿Se instancia el Scheduled en ese momento?

Hemos probado con varias aplicaciones que tenemos de ese estilo y en todas tenemos el mismo comportamiento

Los jobs son de este estilo

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class TestJob {
 
  
  
  

  /** Logger. */
  private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(TestJob.class);
  @Scheduled( fixedDelayString = "1000") 
  public void lanzarTarea() {
      log.debug(" Tarea1 ");
  }


}
```

¿Existe alguna configuración en Spring que permita que el planificador se instancie en el arranque? Y si no ¿Se podría realizar una llamada en el arranque a un servicio REST de forma que se instancie el planificador?

Para que se vea el comportamiento esto son los logs de Tomcat donde se aprecia

```
26-Feb-2021 15:26:26.526 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
26-Feb-2021 15:26:26.526 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
26-Feb-2021 15:27:32.938 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'ServletSpring'
26-Feb-2021 15:28:56.020 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
26-Feb-2021 15:28:57.270 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
26-Feb-2021 15:28:57.270 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
26-Feb-2021 15:29:12.681 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'ServletSpring'
26-Feb-2021 15:29:34.561 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
26-Feb-2021 15:29:34.562 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
26-Feb-2021 15:29:34.570 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'ServletSpring'
26-Feb-2021 15:30:06.448 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
26-Feb-2021 15:30:07.976 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
26-Feb-2021 15:30:07.976 INFORMACIÓN [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()

-- Aquí realizo la petición rest. 
26-Feb-2021 15:30:31.939 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'ServletSpring'
```

Aquí el localhost_acces_log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2021:15:29:15 +0100] "GET /sceem/services/test HTTP/1.1" 200 463
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2021:15:29:15 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
```

Y Aquí de Catalina

```
26-Feb-2021 15:30:09.451 INFORMACIÓN [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 6901 ms
26-Feb-2021 15:30:31.939 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Initializing Servlet 'ServletSpring'
26-Feb-2021 15:30:34.056 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.finishRegistration No TaskScheduler/ScheduledExecutorService bean found for scheduled processing
26-Feb-2021 15:30:34.092 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Completed initialization in 2153 ms
```

Después del arranque, hasta que no se hace una primera petición rest no instancia a InitServletBean

Comment: Debería funcionar tal y como lo tienes puesto. ¿Estás seguro de que tienes el log en nivel debug? Por defecto creo que está en "info", con lo que ese mensaje no aparecería

Comment: No. Este es un ejemplo sencillo que hicimos para detectar el problema y de primeras no escribe logs pero en el momento que se hace una llamada a un servicio REST cualquiera empieza a funcionar de repente. Nos ha llevado bastante tiempo detectar el problema porque en las aplicaciones que se basan en servicios REST es difícil que no haya habido una llamada desde el arranque.

Comment: He realizado una prueba y me funcionan son problemas, también tengo proyectos con 100 procesos y nunca he tenido ese problema, si puedes crea un proyecto en Github de tú prueba y así podemos ejecutarla.

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas alguna configuración extraña que no instancie los componentes al inicio, algo como @Lazy

Comment: Muchas gracias.He encontrado la causa.

Se debe a la configuración del servlet DispatcherServlet en el fichero web.xml.

Para ello basta con establecer la propiedad del servlet load-on-startup a 1 
``` xml 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletSpring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: @gynch ponlo como respuesta, por favor. Con eso los demás saben cómo resolverlo. Es más, en un rato podrás marcarla como respuesta aceptada :)

Comment: @Alfabravo Lo he intentado pero no me deja añadir respuestas, así que al menos lo pongo en comentarios por si a alguien le puede servir

Comment: No te sale abajo una caja con título Tu Respuesta? No te deja poner todo esto allí? Es la primera vez que pasa, le notificaré a los moderadores...

Comment: @Alfabravo el usuario esta bloqueado para responder por el sistema. Nada que podamos hacer de nuestra parte...

Answer (score 0):

Escribo la respuesta. La puse en su momento como comentario porque en ese momento tenía bloqueado responder preguntas por el sistema.

Se debe a la configuración del servlet DispatcherServlet en el fichero web.xml. Para ello basta con establecer la propiedad del servlet load-on-startup a 1

````xml
    <servlet> 
          <servlet-name>ServletSpring</servlet-name> 
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
          <init-param> 
                 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
                  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet> ```
````